# Apparently duplicate tables in newMips Database schema

Tags: newmips

In the newMips database, the 2 tables `user` and `*_e_user` have (almost) the same data. Why? What is the role of each tables?

I guess the answer will help me to understand why the tables `role` and `*_e_role` contain different data.

Answer (score 0):

Table user is to manage users of the generator itself. 
Table *_e_user is to manage users of generated applications.